# display:none a div on condition if siblings child div is empty

Tags: javascript

)

I'm trying to hide the text "Produktgrundpreis (falls vorhanden):" if the siblings child div is empty.
[That's how the site looks like atm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXUBM.png)

Here's the DOM
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSAIC.png)

```
<div id="Produktgrundpreis-Text" class="brz-css-kfrku brz-css-iwlmt brz-wrapper">
  <div class="brz-rich-text brz-css-psnqi" data-custom-id="nvnuscfnezabbinlagscfvcigqzzhejoypkb">
    <div>
      <p class="brz-css-zpfqz" data-uniq-id="wuxnq" data-generated-css="brz-css-vtvig">
        <span class="brz-cp-color7">Produktgrundpreis (falls vorhanden):</span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="Produktgrundpreis-Shortcode" class="brz-css-kfrku brz-css-eburp brz-wrapper">
  <div class="brz-wp-shortcode brz-css-fciet" data-custom-id="xfbqskiqkijowmwcilpwfpsdgetytiwoqvto">
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm an absolute JS beginner and tried the following code I scratched together by myself:

```
function pgpSichtbarkeit() {
  var pgpShortcode = document.getElementById('Produktgrundpreis-Shortcode').innerText;
  
  console.log(pgpShortcode)

  if (pqpShortcode.includes('')) {
    document.getElementById('Produktgrundpreis-Text').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

As the text content of Produktgrundpreis-Shortcode is empty, I thought I could get over that way and use .innerText.
What could I do better?

Comment: `trim()` it then do `if (pqpShortcode === '') {` instead, though you might want to do it in reverse, hide it then show it if it has content else you will have some cumulative layout shifting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since empty ('') is falsy value you can use [false value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) check.
You can also use trim if you think there can be space (' ')

```
function pgpSichtbarkeit() {
  var pgpShortcode = document.getElementById('Produktgrundpreis-Shortcode').innerText;
  // if (!pgpShortcode.trim())
  if (!pgpShortcode) {
      document.getElementById('Produktgrundpreis-Text').style.display = "none";
  }
}

pgpSichtbarkeit();
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This helped!

Could you please explain what you did? It would help my learning curve :-)

Comment: `.innerText` will get us all text  inside div with id `Produktgrundpreis-Shortcode` and we will check if this text does not have anything `if (!pgpShortcode)` then we will hide div with id `Produktgrundpreis-Text`. For more info on falsy value visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the length value of "innerText".

```js
function pgpShortcode() {
  var pgpShortcodeLength = document.getElementById('Produktgrundpreis-Shortcode').innerText.length;

if (pgpShortcodeLength < 1) {
    document.getElementById('Produktgrundpreis-Text').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
  min-height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Produktgrundpreis-Text" class="brz-css-kfrku brz-css-iwlmt brz-wrapper">
  
<div class="brz-rich-text brz-css-psnqi" data-custom-id="nvnuscfnezabbinlagscfvcigqzzhejoypkb">
  
  <div>
<p class="brz-css-zpfqz" data-uniq-id="wuxnq" data-generated-css="brz-css-vtvig">
<span class="brz-cp-color7">Produktgrundpreis (falls vorhanden):</span>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="Produktgrundpreis-Shortcode" class="brz-css-kfrku brz-css-eburp brz-wrapper">
  
<div class="brz-wp-shortcode brz-css-fciet" data-custom-id="xfbqskiqkijowmwcilpwfpsdgetytiwoqvto"><div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<button onclick="pgpShortcode()">Check</button>
```